# Find threshold in pyspark dataframe data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I'm totally new to dataframes and pyspark in general.

In python what I want to do is trivial - however I can't seem to find a method which doesn't take ages using pyspark.

I have a pyspark dataframe with approx 4000 rows with a schema as follows:

```
root
 |-- waveformData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- elements: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- dimensions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

Each array is approx 20000 doubles.

Searching this array to find a max value and threshold (first instance of 50% of max value) takes very little time - but only once the data is in a 'normal' format (numpy array).

I am using a basic:

```
wav_df = temp_data.select("waveformData").toPandas()
wav = wav_df.to_numpy()[0][0].get("elements")
```

and then searching for max / threshold

But the 'toPandas' step takes forever (like 30 seconds for a single row)

Why?

I've been trying to operate on the pyspark dataframe to avoid this conversion using .collect and the like, but everything I try takes ages.

If pyspark is meant for big data, I must be doing it wrong, there's no way this is the normal processing time for this amount of data.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you also add some test data for waveformData, so I can create a dataframe using that test data, to see what can be done

Comment: How's best to add it, I can't paste a 20000 element array.

Comment: I think I found the issue, I was loading the rows one at a time and converting to pandas, if I convert all 4000 at once it seems MUCH quicker, but then I ran out of memory :(

Comment: Failed with the following error message:

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 1286 tasks (1025.2 MiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MiB)

Comment: I tried using:

spark.driver.maxResultSize <4>g

But got 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'driver'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created some random test data

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


n = 20000
for i in range(100):
    df = spark.createDataFrame([
        Row(waveFormData=Row(elements=[float(v) for v in np.random.randn(n)], dimensions=[n])) for i in range(40)
    ])
    df.write.parquet('waveFormData.parquet', mode='append')
```

When I load the data and select the max of the arrays that ran through within 2 seconds:

```py
df = spark.read.parquet('waveFormData.parquet')

df.select(F.array_max('waveFormData.elements')).toPandas()
```

Comment: OK, so write as parquet, then read back and convert to pandas? I'll try that. Many thanks. Will this solve the memory issue I had as well? From what I found it was pulling all data from the cluster into the driver and using too much memory. Does using Parquet solve that?

Comment: Many thanks, this does work well, I can see that operating on the parquet data is much faster. 

Quick question - after the F.max operation, does the data keep the same indexing? It seems to be sorting it as well...

Comment: There is no row index in Spark dataframes. When working with Spark you generally cannot rely on the ordering of the data (not sure whether this is what you mean by "indexing"). You should probably create your own sortable row id on your input data. Maybe `F.row_number()` or `F.monotonically_increasing_id()`could be helpful here.

Comment: What was the original format of the input data?

Comment: OK, I'll try adding a row_number column

Not sure how to answer the original format question, I get a pyspark dataframe, that's all I know. I've only been using this for a day, please forgive my ignorance!

Comment: After using:

maxs = up_data_par.select(F.array_max('waveformData.elements')).toPandas()

I thought I'd be able to use:

maxs.select(F.array_max('array_max(waveformData.elements)').toPandas()

To get the overall max of that array - why can't I?

Comment: I just get ''DataFrame' object has no attribute 'select' - which seems crazy because I thought 'select()' was one of the really basic functions...

Comment: You switched from Spark-Dataframe to Pandas-Dataframe when you used the method `.toPandas()`. The latter do not have a select-Method. Try
`up_data_par.select(F.array_max('waveformData.elements').alias('maxs')).select(F.max('maxs')).toPandas()`

Comment: Ah, OK. That explains a lot.

Comment: When you say:
"There is no row index in Spark dataframes. When working with Spark you generally cannot rely on the ordering of the data"
Does this mean that the data frame I originally downloaded could be randomly ordered?!
I want to compare (and extract values based upon) indexes from a second dataframe, is this impossible?

Comment: The exact behavior depends on your data source, but generally speaking: yes, it is most likely randomly ordered. You should really get some kind of ID column that you can use to join the two dataframes.

Comment: It's OK, I can sort by a timestamp, both dataframes hold data with the same timestamp, so (I hope) by using df_sorted = df.sort('acqStamp') on both will mean they are in the same order.

Comment: In this case, also select the timestamp column and sort in the end. Sorting at the beginning is not necessarily preserved. Or do an actual `.join()` with the other DF, this would be the "proper" way of doing it. :)

Comment: OK, so the sort seems to work, on an example of 1 :P

What I'd really like to do is extract some rows of one (pyspark) dataframe, based on a column from a pandas dataframe ('index') - is there an easy way of doing this? (btw, thank you so much for all the help already!)

I have ~9000 rows in the first data frame, and I want to extract ~4000 of them by index.  Now they are sorted I know the index will match. Alternatively I can extract when the acqStamps are the same, but that seemed like a longer process.

Comment: Things get much easier when both tables are either Spark or Pandas DFs. In both frameworks there are `INNER JOIN` operations that will filter both dataframes to the entries that are present in both tables.

Comment: OK,  that's good because both tables started as spark dataframes - I'll look at that. 

Last question - you showed me how to do a max on every spark row array quickly, is there a way to find the first instance of the array going over a given value (so I can find a threshold)?

Comment: I do not, but there might be a way. I'm not very familiar with nested dataframes. I would recommend you to flatten your table (i.e. transform it into a flat table with columns array_date, array_id, element_id, value) and then use the "normal" Spark SQL functions (probably including groupby- and Window-functions) to do your analyses

Comment: Got it working with UDF. Thanks you SO MUCH for your help!!